# Mule IDE plugin for Eclipse url not working (http://dist.muleforge.org/mule-ide/updates-2.1.x/)

Tags: eclipse, mule

Mule id plugin  Url is not working. Can any one help to get an alternate url for the same plugin.

http://dist.muleforge.org/mule-ide/updates-2.1.x/

This url is also mentioned in the below tutorial.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Installing+Mule+ESB+3+and+the+Mule+IDE

Below is the error which i am receiving after accessing this url in browser.

Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

Answer (score 0):

Mule version 2X uses the url :- http://dist.muleforge.org/mule-ide/updates-2.1.x/  and for Mule version 3X the url :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Installing+Mule+ESB+3+and+the+Mule+IDE  is being used.
You need to check the version of Mule you are using and need to use the url that matches your Mule version.
If you are using Mule Enterprise edition you can take support from the MuleSoft Support, else if you are not using Enterprise you can post the issue in their forum

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt there is still support for the Mule IDE, it was deprecated in favour of Mule Studio (that then became Anypoint Studio).

Do you really need to do a new development on Mule 2.x? If not, please consider using the much better [Anypoint studio](http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/mule-studio). If you need to stick to the 2.x version, you could just use a vanilla version of eclipse that will take care of the the autocompletion and then export to the apps directory of a running mule container for a hot deployment.